# Pause setInterval on hover via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
setInterval(function(){ $("#nav #nextslide").click()},10000);
```

It works. But I have `a` tag:

```
<a href="site.html" class="gallery form_click">click.</a>
```

I want, when mouseover on gallery button, pause timer. When mouseout, setInterval active again.

Tried this but not working:

```
$('a.gallery').hover(function(ev){
    clearInterval(timer);
}, function(ev){
    setInterval(function(){ $("#nav #nextslide").click()},10000);
});
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: You aren't showing enough code, is `timer` a variable that your `setInterval` is assigned to?

Answer (score 6):

You need to store the `timer` reference into a variable to clear it later

```
//declare it in a shared scope
var timer;

function startTimer() {
    timer = setInterval(function () {
        $("#nav #nextslide").click()
    }, 10000);
}

$('a.gallery').hover(function (ev) {
    clearInterval(timer);
}, function (ev) {
    startTimer();
});
startTimer();
```

Answer (score 0):

step 1:

```
function example(){  $("#nav #nextslide").click() //code you want ot execute inside setInterval() }
```

step 2:

```
var timer= setInterval(example(); ,10000);
```

step 3:

```
$('a.gallery').hover(function(ev){
    clearInterval(timer);
}, function(ev){
    timer=setInterval(example(); ,10000);
});
```

I've tested it, working fine.